# How to build Flask-admin model view depending on user

Tags: python, flask, permissions, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

How to control permissions on flask-admin view?
For example, current_user.has_role() not in ('administrator', 'editor') -> MyModelView.can_create = False

[example of Auth flask-admin](http://examples.flask-admin.org/auth/admin/#)

If after login in _handle_view method I add

```
self.can_create = False
```

Logically, there should be no "create" option in all ModelView_for_Admin models, but it is. Nor way, ModelViewExt works just if switch their names in add_view method below.

P.S. I want users with certain roles could do exact things:

1) can or can't create rows,

2) can\can't delete

3) can edit only themselves rows, nor others (only if they haven't administrator role)

4) etc.

Or another question: how to build simple CRUD site, with all this ACL, if I was wrong choosing flask-admin ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should not to implement code in builtint _handle_view, but in is_active method.